# my code sleep on response.read() function, sometimes

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
for index in range(1,10):
    send_headers = {
                    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2;rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0',
                    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Connection':'keep-alive'
    }

    try:
        req=urllib2.Request(url,headers=send_headers)
        response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
        sleeptime=random.randint(1,30*index)
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        traceback.print_exc()
        sleeptime=random.randint(13,40*index)
        print url
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
        continue
    if response.getcode() != 200:
        continue
    else:
        break
return response.read()
```

I found that my code sleep on return `response.read()` sometimes, but the program is not dead and there is no error or exception, and I do not know why and how it happens. How can I fix it?

It is python, I want to get some picture on web.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have a `time.sleep()` statement, that's why it sleeps for a random amount of time.

Comment: I debug my code, and I found that it stopped at response.read() with no error no exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it maybe slept because of connection timeout.

urllib.urlopen can set timeout via timeout parameter.( python3 )

If not setted, then socket default timeout will be used.

and Default socket timeout is -1.0 that is no setting, no timeout.

so try this,

```
response=urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=3)
```

or, in python2

```
import socket
setdefaulttimeout(3.0)
```

anyway, using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead of urllib2

Answer (score 0):

`response.read` reads the HTTP response from the server. It may take a while because reading involves waiting for the bytes to arrive over the network.

Getting resources from the web takes time, there's no way around this.

That said, you can access the network in a non-blocking way and get notified when the data is available. This will not change the fact that getting resources takes time.